# Add server data to index.html

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jinja2, create-react-app

I have a simple app build with [Create React App](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app). I'd like to inject some server data in a jinja template. Obviously local webpack server can't parse jinja

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.SERVER_DATA = {
      "company": {{ company|dumps|escapejson }}
    };
</script>
```

I don't have the access to `process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production"` in index.html. **Is there any other flag that I could use?**

Alternatively, I could use [try and catch](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#injecting-data-from-the-server-into-the-page)

```
   try {
     window.SERVER_DATA = __SERVER_DATA__;
    } catch(e) {
      console.info('Development MODE', e)
      window.SERVER_DATA = {};
    }
```

But that's a syntax error.

Comment: I would look into using e.g. Webpack if you want access to NODE_ENV in index.html, that's how Vue creates its developer/production versions when you build a Vue app.

Comment: @SimonHyll There is no `process` in index.html

Comment: No, but you can generate index.html, or index.js, to have the process.NODE_ENV variable set to 'production' or 'development', since presumably you'll be generating your website for either development or release and that's what you want to get, right? So just make your generator (Webpack is my recommendation) insert that variable into your code. Easy peasy.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the best thing to do is to catch the error

```
try {
  window.pagedata = __SERVER_DATA__;
} catch(e) {
  console.info('Dev mode');
}
```

and then

```
settings_page = render_template('index.html')
return settings_page.replace(
    '__SERVER_DATA__', escapejson(dumps(server_data))
)
```